# onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad 2

Tags: android, admob, android-studio-3.0, admob-rewardedvideoad

My code is working in *app1*(worked with the test ads id and real ads id) and I copied AdMob code from *app1* to *app2* and update real app id with test app id, but when run *app2* test ads is not showing and it showing this error "`onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad`" with error code 2 
what to do?

```
MobileAds.initialize(mContext, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

errorcode 2 means "The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity." But in same page other products are listing , they are fetching from api
Autodate correcting on your device :True

I restart app and tried agane but ads not working

I test some other app with ads and they are working with out any problem

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error (code error = 2) when i used a id of banner not reward id, check that use the good id reward